# ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(121)] Failed to launch GPU process

Tags: macos, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal-services

i am trying to configure debugging port for google chrome extension for Visual studio for client side debugging in terminal using below commands and getting the below error,

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222`

`[96138:85251:0321/103001.249367:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(121)] Failed to launch GPU process.`

`Created new window in existing browser session.`

i have tried `export BROWSER=google-chrome` too, but its not working. i hope i have to type this command in terminal . I am using MAC high Sierra , How can i resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when working with the bokeh python3 library on Ubuntu 16.04. I found a solution on a thread for jupyter notebook on github.

From: [Github Issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2836)

> I had this same error
>   ("ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(108)] Failed to launch GPU
>   process"). After running jupyter notebook, I would get a new tab in
>   google-chrome, but it would be blank.
>
> Following but slightly modifying @wewan's advice, I ran "export
>   BROWSER=google-chrome". Then running jupyter notebook worked as
>   expected. I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Google Chrome 62.0.3202.62, and
>   Jupyter 4.3.0. Also, if this works, you'll obviously want to add the
>   export command to your .bashrc or .bash_profile

I did a raw export at the command line, and it corrected my issue.

```
export BROWSER=google-chrome
```

If this works, you will want to add this to your profile. I am not well-versed with Macs, but I believe there is a .bashrc file to which you can add the export.